# Change image tint color memory leaks

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiimage, tintcolor

I have the following code which I use to change the tint color of an image:

```
imageView.image = theImageView.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
imageView.tintColor = UIColor.green
```

One concern that I haven´t been able to find out about is if this uses a lot of memory to do? Is it simply better to just get the icons in the tint color I need directly or doesn´t the above code draw much memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will not be any memory issues when you re-render your images `tintColor`. The re-rendering does not use any memory. Although I would recommend if have the right colors on your icons when you load them as assets if possible.